# Can I emulate Acrobat scroll wheel zoom shortcuts in PS?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I have used a whole bunch of applications e.g. Acrobat, Inkscape, SumatraPDF, Foxit that use the following shortcuts for zooming and panning,

- Scrollwheel = pan up/down
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Scrollwheel = pan left/right
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Scrollwheel = Zoom in/out

Is it possible to get this behaviour in PS with a plugin or something? I realise there is an either/or option for setting scrollwheel to pan or zoom but not both with a modifier.

I could use the tools and default shortcuts but they are really clunky and require me to move to and from the mouse, esp. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+/-</kbd> to zoom in/out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the movement shortcuts that I commonly use in Photoshop:

- <kbd>Scrollwheel</kbd>: Pan up/down
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Scrollwheel</kbd>: Pan left/right
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Scrollwheel</kbd>: Zoom in/out

You can hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> with any of these to pan or zoom in at a greater magnitude. I am not aware of any way to modify these shortcuts.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that covers all the bases but is annoyingly different to, say Acrobat, or a bunch of other established products ...

Comment: @Brendan it's at least consistent between Photoshop and Illustrator, which is a bit of a surprise. Consistency across programs is not one of Adobe's strong suits ;)

Comment: Hmm, that's kind of annoying. I'm only just starting to use Adobe's products beyond Acrobat and having to re-calibrate my brain is really jarring. Thanks though!